# If she floats then she is not a witch like we thought

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, homework

Continuing my C++ saga, this is the third project for my CS1 class:

> Buoyancy is the ability of an object to float.  Archimedes' principle
>   states that the buoyant force is equal to the weight of the fluid that
>   is displaced by the submerged object.  The buoyant force can be
>   computed by
>
> $$ F_b = V \cdot y $$
>
> where \$ F_b \$ is the buoyant force. \$ V \$ is the volume of the
>   submerged object, and \$ y \$ is the specific weight of the fluid.  If
>   \$ F_b \$ is greater than or equal to the weight of the object, then
>   it will float, otherwise it will sink.
>
> Write a program that inputs the weight (in pounds) and radius (in
>   feet) of a sphere and outputs whether the sphere will sink or float in
>   water.  Use \$ y = 62.4 \dfrac{\text{lb}}{\text{ft}^3} \$ as the
>   specific weight of water.  The volume of a sphere is computed by \$ \left( \dfrac{4}{3} \right) \pi r^3\$.

Additionally, I must have a loop in this program that allows the user to run it as many times as they want to. I have to ask the user each time whether they want to continue.

It is also supposed to be fully commented, which I think I have done within reason.

**`buoyancy.cpp`**:

```
/**
 * @file buoyancy.cpp
 * @brief Calculates if a sphere will sink or float in water given the weight and radius
 * @author syb0rg
 * @date 9/12/14
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

/**
 * Sphere
 * @var weight The weight of the sphere
 * @var radius The height of the sphere
 */
struct Sphere
{
    double weight = 0;
    double radius = 0;
};

/**
 * Resets the command line so we can input data again, and signals user to re-enter proper data
 */
void resetConsole()
{
    std::cin.clear(); // clear the error flag that was set so that future I/O operations will work correctly
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skips to the next newline
    std::cout << "Invalid input.  Please enter a positive number: ";
}

int main()
{
    constexpr double waterBuoyancy = 62.4;
    Sphere obj;
    char again = '\0';
    do
    {
        // get input for height, re-read input if not a positive number
        std::cout << "Enter the weight in pounds: ";
        while(!(std::cin >> obj.weight) || obj.weight < 0) resetConsole();

        // get input for radius, re-read input if not a positive number
        std::cout << "Enter the radius in inches: ";
        while(!(std::cin >> obj.radius) || obj.radius < 0) resetConsole();

        double volume = ((4/3) * M_PI * pow(obj.radius, 3));
        double bouyantForce = volume * waterBuoyancy;

        if (obj.weight <= bouyantForce) std::cout << "The object will float." << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "The object will sink." << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Run the program again (y/N): ";
        std::cin.get();  // absorb newline character from previous input
        std::cin.get(again);
        again = tolower(again);
        if ('\n' == again) again = 'n';
    } while (again == 'y');
}
```

Comment: - If she weighs the same as a duck...- she's made of wood. http://www.qedcat.com/moviemath/holy_grail.html

Comment: Not worth an answer by itself, but you have `The weight of the sphere` and `The height of the sphere` and *no indication of what units they use*. If you're lucky, whoever's maintaining this code realizes that the units are missing and tracks them down. If you're unlucky, they assume it's whatever units they're used to, and [you lose half a billion dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter).

Comment: re: the title - witches float. dunking was a no win test

Comment: You need to separate your (console app) view from your (buoyancy) model. ... May be overkill but ideally std::cout shouldn't be in the same class as your actual physics logic.

Comment: Apparently the water density is expressed in `lb/ft^3`, but the radius is in `in` and the volume of the sphere is consequently in `in^3`. You miss a factor here (whatever is the relation between `ft` and `in` is)

Comment: I always loved how incredibly absurd the Salem Witchcraft Trials were, especially the part with the sinking and floating. "Alright, we're going to tie you up and throw you into this deep water. If you float, *you're a witch*! But if you sink and *drown* and **die**, then you're fine. So, in that case, uhhh... sorry for the mistake. Oh well, now you're dead. Whoops."

Comment: In your comment, the radius of a sphere is not its "height".

Comment: ... that title had me too interested.

Comment: Yeah, [Nirvana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogsEw7wuimk)!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several small things that you can improve:

- `double weight = 0;` works fine, but `double weight = 0.0;` would be more pedantic since `weight` is a `double`.
- By the way, the following line is a good example to illustrate the benefits of literals pedantry:

  ```
  double volume = ((4/3) * M_PI * pow(obj.radius, 3));
  ```

  Here, `4/3` performs an integer division and not a floating point one; that expression will yield `1` instead of `1.333333333` (I doubt that you want it to yield `1`). You should change it to `4.0/3.0` to get the desired result.
- That said, there is another problem with the aforementioned line: `M_PI` is not standard C++. It is not standard C either. It is a standard POSIX addition to `<math.h>`. You should rewrite your own constants or use Boost ones for examples if you want your code to be portable.
- Speaking of `<math.h>`... You are using C++, therefore you should use the C++ standard library headers too and not the C ones:

  ```
  #include <cmath>
  ```
- And you notably forgot to include the header `<ctype.h>` for `std::tolower`.
- That said, it is good practice in C++ to fully qualify the names of the functions from the standard library: you should write `std::tolower` (and thus actually include `<cctype>` instead  of `<ctype.h>`). It's not really longer and it may help to prevent name clashes (I doubt that you will have problems with `tolower`, but it can be worse with some more common names).

Comment: On your final bullet - `std::tolower` is required if you include `<cctype>`, and `tolower` is required if you include `<ctype.h>`.  Don't mix the two.

Comment: @TobySpeight You're being overly pedantic :p Fixed it anyway.

Comment: "Pedantic" is my middle name at work, particularly when reviewing code.  :-)

Answer (score 17):

### Bugs

You calculate the volume of the sphere incorrectly!

### Style

- You misspelled the variable `bouyantForce`.
- The constant `waterBuoyancy` is a misnomer.  It should be `waterDensity`.
- There's not much point to `struct Sphere`.  You haven't defined any methods in it, nor do you use it to facilitate parameter passing.  You might as well have two independent variables named `weight` and `radius`.  (You could also take the other approach, which is to make it a class.)
- Instead of (or in addition to) defining `resetConsole()`, you could define a `askDouble(promptString)` function instead.  That would reduce repetition and make your `main()` easier to follow.

Comment: Good points. I agree with most of them, but I think `struct Sphere` is more expressive, than having two independent variables. Not for an OOP reason, but to provide context.

Answer (score 16):

> ```
> char again = '\0';
> ```

No need for setting a value. You overwrite it before using anyway.

> ```
> do 
> {
>     // ...
>     if ('\n' == again) again = 'n';
> } while (again == 'y');
> ```

The `if` here seems pointless. If `again` is not `'y'`, you will exit the loop anyway, so setting `again = 'n'` seems pointless, together with the `if`.

Although you created a `struct` for `Sphere`, it doesn't have much purpose in this code. The `Sphere` is not doing much for you. You set its weight and radius, and then using those fields directly to calculate the volume. It would make sense to move the calculation of the volume inside `Sphere`. That way, the object would have more purpose: users wouldn't have to worry about how the volume is calculated, the logic would be encapsulated inside.

You can imagine different kind of objects implementing an appropriate `volume` method. You could have a collection of such objects, and not need to know how to calculate their volume from their internal properties, but simply ask their `volume` method.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the `struct`, you can just keep it in `main()` if you'll just be creating an instance and possibly passing an instance to another function.  Keep in mind that `struct`s are `public` by default in C++.

Adding on to what @200_success has mentioned, you *can* add more to it, such as an initializer list to give an instance starting values, `operator>>` overload to input directly into fields, and `operator<<` overload to display fields of an instance directly.  You may even find `operator>>` to be more streamline than accessing the individual fields (you can have the overload take both input values at once).

Essentially, you can utilize these things, along with @janos' volume calculation idea, to make `Sphere` a more useful structure.  If something belongs to a `Sphere`, keep it within the structure so that the user can let `Sphere` handle it.

The final `struct Sphere` can look something like this:

```
struct Sphere
{
    double weight;
    double radius;

    Sphere(double weight, double radius)
        : weight(weight)
        , radius(radius)
    {}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Sphere& obj)
{
    return in >> obj.weight >> obj.radius;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Sphere const& obj)
{
    out << "Weight: " << obj.weight;
    out << "\nRadius: " << obj.radius;
    return out;
}
```

(The respective overloads require `<istream>` and `<ostream>`, *not* `<iostream>`.)

Note that the overloads are defined outside the `struct`.  While it is still okay to have them inside as `friend` functions, [Scott Meyers recommends non-member non-`friend` whenever possible](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

This doesn't do any input validation (`operator>>` could handle the validation), but you can implement that however you'd like.  Even without this extra code, the `struct` may fit better in a separate file, but with this simple implementation, it may be a little overkill.  This should at least give you some ideas.